# passport.js passport.authenticate() always return 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, passport.js

I have a route below

```
router.get('/list', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), listService.fetch);
```

Now when I make a request to list end point I always get `401 unauthorized`.

I change above route to below to see what is happening.

```
router.get('/list', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', (err, user, info) => {
    console.log('ERR: ', err); // returns null
    console.log('USER: ', user); // returns false
    console.log('INFO: ', info);  /// undefined
}, listService.fetch);
```

But as you can see that there is no error and no user and info with above approach.

In passport.js I am using the Scheme

```
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT');
```

To login user, I am using jwt sign method like

```
var token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), 'secret', {
      expiresIn: 10080
    });
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here and how to fix.

Comment: can you share your request for which you are getting 401 error?

Comment: Finally I resolved this one. In my UserSchema I used set('toJSON'). After removing that it starts working.